# Odd order subgroups of $PSL(2.q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let q be an odd prime power. Is it true that every odd order subgroup of $PSL(2,q)$ is abelian ? If yes, how can it be proven ?

Comment: No it's not true. For example ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$ has a nonabelian subgroup of order $21$.

Comment: Thanks Derek. It seemed too good to be true.

Comment: This paper of O. King on the subgroups of the linear groups will help you:

The subgroup structure of finite classical groups in terms of geometric configurations.

Comment: Thanks very much  Amin. I will have a look at it.